# Where does Cargo put the git requirements?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

When compiling a project, cargo automatically downloads the requirements, specified in the Cargo.toml, given as a git-repository.

E.g.

```
[dependencies.piston]
git = "https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/piston"
```

will result in

```
Updating git repository 'https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/opengl_graphics'
```

when compiling. Where does it save those repositories on my disk? I'm using Windows, does this change anything?

Comment: It is `$HOME/.cargo` on linux and I don't see why it would be different on windows.

Comment: it isn't, see `%USERPROFILE%\.cargo`. but I don't know where it's documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man cargo` gives:

```
FILES
       ~/.cargo
              Directory  in which Cargo stores repository data. Cargo can
              be instructed to use a .cargo subdirectory in  a  different
              location by setting the CARGO_HOME environment variable.
```

Doing a `git grep` for `CARGO_HOME` finds https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/3533ff11c505017751d1e466685efe7084cbd96b/src/cargo/util/config.rs#L380-L384

which uses http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/os/fn.homedir.html