# Where are modules installed by Cargo stored in a Rust project?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

In NodeJS, all the packages installed by NPM are stored in the `node_modules/` directory. Is there any such directory in Rust? Are the crates installed somewhere globally?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Crates are installed globally for the current user, not per project. Currently, they are stored in `<user directory>/.cargo/registry`.

- Mac: `/Users/<username>/.cargo/registry`
- Or, in general on Mac, Linux & Unix: `$HOME/.cargo/registry`
- Windows 10: `\Users\<username>\.cargo\registry`

There is an [RFC in progress](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1615) to standardise this, and use the location that users of each platform would more likely expect.

See also:

- [How can the location of Cargo's configuration directory be overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38050995/155423)
- [Where does Cargo put the git requirements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28069678/155423)